# returning large string representation from a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, return, tuples

I have a function that takes a list of Books and returns one large string of each book followed by a newline character.

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')

Book('Suzane Collins','The Hunger Games', 'Fiction', 2008, 6.96, 20),
Book('J.K. Rowling', "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 'Fantasy', 1997, 4.78, 12)
```

I made the following function:

```
def Booklist_display(dlist):
    for item in dlist:
        return '{name} {price} {stock}'.format(name=item.name, price=item.price, stock=item.instock)
```

But it only prints the first book and not the second book.

```
 Suzane Collins 6.96 20
```

Can someone help me understand if I have the code correct and why my function just prints the first part only? I can't seem to pin point the logic.

Comment: @YuHao. The result should be what its printing..but it should print all the elements in that list, not just one. The result should be one large string consisting of the string representation of each book followed by a newline ('\n') character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this `for` loop:

```
for item in dlist:
    return '{name} {price} {stock}'.format(name=item.name, price=item.price, stock=item.instock)
```

The function exits when the loop iterates over the first object (because of `return`).

Store the result in a list and return later:

```
strlist = []
for item in dlist:
    strlist.append('{name} {price} {stock}'.format(name=item.name, price=item.price, stock=item.instock))
return '\n'.join(strlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` together with a list comprehension.

```
from collections import named tuple

Book = namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')

books = [Book('Suzane Collins','The Hunger Games', 'Fiction', 2008, 6.96, 20),
         Book('J.K. Rowling', "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 'Fantasy', 1997, 4.78, 12)]

def Booklist_display(dlist):
    return '\n'.join(['{title} {price} {stock}'
                      .format(title=item.title, price=item.price, stock=item.instock)
                      for item in dlist])

>>> Booklist_display(books)
"The Hunger Games 6.96 20\nHarry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone 4.78 12"
```